# Semiotics & identity research

Tags: semiotics

I'm studying the use of semiotics and the link to identity, I wondered if anyone could point me towards any research they knew of?

I'm already reading The Semiotic Stance, Paul Kockelman 2005 & his later work on identities.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks. :)

(PS. FACEWORK is also relevant in my research).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Perhaps you could indicate what kind of work you have in mind? Two or three sentences about the volume you mentioned might be enlightening. ;)

Comment: Thanks! :) Kockelman outlines what semiotics is, and how a sign, an object and an interpretant are related to one another. 
Some not dissimilar papers in the area of sociolinguistics which I am reading are Bob Le Pages work on acts of identity & Bucholtz and Hall stuff. (Sorry if this is quite vague, I am only beginning my undergraduate research into this area).